# Shifting row data in xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have multiple Rows data in my XML like this -

```
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
    <R1>English1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
    <R1>Maths1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="1">
    <R1>Code1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
    <R1>English2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
    <R1>Maths2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="2">
    <R1>Code2</R1>
</ROW>
```

I want my Output to be displayed in Image like that this ROW data works in a for-each loop. And the requirement is that ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="1" should be displayed first then its ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" data. Moving further in loop again, ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="2" should be displayed first then its ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" data.

Basically it should come like this -

```
Code1
  English1
  Maths1
Code2
  English2
  Maths2
```

The XSLT code works for sequence as for-2each loop works. But I need to shift the TOTAL row first for that ID. Please suggest logic for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kRowById"
      match="ROW[not(@TYPE='TOTAL')]" use="@ID"/>

 <xsl:template match="ROW[@TYPE='TOTAL']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRowById', @ID)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML** (wrapped into a single top element to be made a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
        <R1>English1</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
        <R1>Maths1</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="1">
        <R1>Code1</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
        <R1>English2</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
        <R1>Maths2</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="2">
        <R1>Code2</R1>
    </ROW>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted result** (in which the wanted elements are re-ordered:

```
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="1">
   <R1>Code1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
   <R1>English1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
   <R1>Maths1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="2">
   <R1>Code2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
   <R1>English2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
   <R1>Maths2</R1>
</ROW>
```

Comment: Thanks, your logic did worked in a desired manner. One more thing is if I have different more elements than these described ones, now when I apply this logic to complete xml then it first displays empty elements for ROWS data and then repeat the same ROW data elements with value.

Comment: @Kundan, Please, ask a *new* SO question and provide a representative XML document and the exact wanted result. I will be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks, but that problem is solved. I would like to as here concerning with this xml part only. I presented my XML with 2 ROW_TYPE (Specification and Total). I can more than this ROw_TYPE which can hold any value. So this code is skipping the other ones. Please suggest.

Comment: @Kundan, Please, ask a new question and explain well -- I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I have added a new question, please check.