# Row Data in xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have multiple Row elements data in my XML like this -

```
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
    <R1>English1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
    <R1>Maths1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="1">
    <R1>Code1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
    <R1>English2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
    <R1>Maths2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="2">
    <R1>Code2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="MAIN" ID="3">
    <R1>Code3</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="4">
    <R1>English4</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="4">
    <R1>Code4</R1>
</ROW>
```

I want my Output to be displayed in Image like that this ROW data works in a for-each loop. And the requirement is that ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="1" should be displayed first then its ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" data. Moving further in loop again, ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="2" should be displayed first then its ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" data. IF ROW_TYPE is different(can be anything) then it should come as in sequence. It is only specific for SPECIFICATION and TOTAL.

Basically it should come like this -

```
Code1
  English1
  Maths1
Code2
  English2
  Maths2
Code3
Code4
  English4
```

The xslt code works for sequence as for-each loop works. But I need to shift the TOTAL row first for that ID. Please suggest logic for this.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539332/shifting-row-data-in-xsl-1-0 ?

Comment: If you see, there is a small change in this XML. Earlier the logic was specific to 2 type of ROW Data. Now the data is varying.

Comment: So if you had `<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" /><ROW TYPE="MAIN" /><ROW TYPE="TOTAL" />` (I'm omitting the R1s for brevity), how should they be ordered in the result?

Comment: I have displayed above the value of R1s in the order they should be displayed. SPECIFICATION will always be with TOTAL. So I look for ID here as under TOTAL I have SPECIFCATION for a product and for that product ID.MAIN is something different which can appear at any ID. The result should be displayed ID wise but according to type also. for e.g. If ID is 1 then TOTAL should come first then its corresponding SPECIFICATION. same for ID=2. For ID=3 the value should come up.

Comment: What I'm asking is, if you have a `SPECIFICATION`, `MAIN` and `TOTAL`, all for the same ID, how should they be arranged (or is that not a possible situation)?

Comment: Both can differ, but SPECIFICATION will always depend on TOTAL. For different IDs we can have different SPECIFICATION, TOTAL.

Comment: You're not answering my question. How should the order be determined? You haven't clearly defined that.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kRowById"
      match="ROW[not(@TYPE='TOTAL' or @TYPE='MAIN')]"
      use="@ID"/>

 <xsl:template match="ROW[@TYPE='TOTAL' or @TYPE='MAIN']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRowById', @ID)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the XML document** (produced from the provided XML fragment, by wrapping it into a single top element):

```
<t>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
        <R1>English1</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
        <R1>Maths1</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="1">
        <R1>Code1</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
        <R1>English2</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
        <R1>Maths2</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="2">
        <R1>Code2</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="MAIN" ID="3">
        <R1>Code3</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="4">
        <R1>English4</R1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="4">
        <R1>Code4</R1>
    </ROW>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="1">
    <R1>Code1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
    <R1>English1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="1">
    <R1>Maths1</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="2">
    <R1>Code2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
    <R1>English2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="2">
    <R1>Maths2</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="MAIN" ID="3">
    <R1>Code3</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="TOTAL" ID="4">
    <R1>Code4</R1>
</ROW>
<ROW TYPE="SPECIFICATION" ID="4">
    <R1>English4</R1>
</ROW>
```

**Update**:

As per request by the OP in a comment, if any value different from "SPECIFICATION" must be placed at the head of the group, use this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kRowById"
      match="ROW[not(@TYPE='TOTAL' or @TYPE='MAIN')]"
      use="@ID"/>

 <xsl:template match="ROW[not(@TYPE='SPECIFICATION')]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRowById', @ID)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Any suggestion on if ROW_TYPE contains value which can be anything that is not known or what data is coming in Input file.

Comment: @Kundan, There can't be a suggestion if it is not specified what must be done in such case...

Comment: Does it mean if we don't know what data is coming from the client in ROW_TYPE then we cannot display the data as they we are doing it now. ROW_TYPE should be always known first?

Comment: @Kundan, See the update to the answer -- I think I am guessing now your requirement.

Comment: It didn't worked, I guess this is not possible. We always have to know the value for ROW_TYPE.

Comment: @Kundan -- *What* didn't work? I still don't know what you actually want. Please, *edit* the question and make it meaningful.