# XSLT loop through children and put in table 2 children per row?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

Im new to using Umbraco and XSLT. Im not to far out of school and we learned vb.net and asp.net there. Now Im doing a free website for this our local church. They want a staff page, so here was my first solution...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" 

xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:umbraco.contour="urn:umbraco.contour" xmlns:tagsLib="urn:tagsLib" xmlns:BlogLibrary="urn:BlogLibrary" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets umbraco.contour tagsLib BlogLibrary ">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<div class="staffList">
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">

<img src="{staffPhoto}" width="210" height="280"/>  
<p class="introduction"><xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:ReplaceLineBreaks(staffName)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>     
<p class="introduction"><xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:ReplaceLineBreaks(position)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>

</xsl:for-each>
</div>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That is what i managed to get working so far, but that just lists them one at a time down the div. Im looking to reduce the scroll amount on that page and have the space to list two per row in a table. After looking around a good bit while at work today, I still have failed to develop a loop that puts each child's three pieces of info in a table cell.

I expect it to be something like this, but this is erroring on the mod 5

```
<div class="staffList">
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/*[position()mod5=1]">
<xsl:variable name = "current-pos" select="(position()-1) * 5+1"/>
<tr>
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/*[position()&gt;=$current-pos and position() &lt; $current-pos+5]" >
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="staffName"/>
</td>
</xsl:for-each>
</tr>           
</xsl:for-each>         
</table>
</div>
```

Ant direction would help. Like i said this XSLT is totally new to me, and all at the same time im trying to wrap my head around everything else in Umbraco thats new to me. Learning by trail and error here.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Dan

Comment: I am planning to start XSLT using [Reusable XSL Stylesheets and Templates](http://www.tonymarston.net/xml-xsl/reusable-xsl.html) article and [A Dynamic XSL Transformation](http://aspalliance.com/511_A_Dynamic_XSL_Transformation.3). Other references - [Shifting row data in xsl 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539332/shifting-row-data-in-xsl-1-0)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting that error because you need to place spaces before and after the word "mod". On the other hand, the approcach you're using is a bit procedural, and there is a slightly more elegant approach, like this:

```
<div class="staffList">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/*[position() mod 5 = 1]" mode="row" />
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Separate templates -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 5"
                         mode="cell" />
  </tr>           
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="*" mode="cell">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="staffName"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

This does assume though `$currentPage` is simply some single element in the XML source document.  If that's not the case, you could still do this:

```
<div class="staffList">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/*[position() mod 5=1]">
      <xsl:variable name = "current-pos" select="(position()-1) * 5+1"/>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
           select="($currentPage/*)[position() &gt;= $currentPos and
                                    position() &lt; $current-pos + 5]"
           mode="cell"/>             
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</div>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="cell">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="staffName"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```